# Does an inactive Blender prevent Windows from sleeping and/or hibernating?

Tags: windows, system

I use W7 on a ThinkPad, with [hybrid sleep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373229(v=vs.85).aspx) enabled. Sleep/hibernate work as expected without Blender.

When Blender application is loaded (i.e. the application has been launched, but is not rendering anything), the computer never enters sleep mode, ignoring sleep timers. The display is off, but fan air is hot, an indication of a sustained CPU/GPU use.

Is there some Blender documentation about this? Is there a solution to prevent it?

---

I'm aware of [how to pause the Blender process](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1666/how-to-stop-blender-from-making-the-cpu-overheat), but my question is different.

Comment: I don't know if Blender disable sleep/hibernate, because my rig is always ON. But if you let Blender running and do nothing, it should use CPU or GPU very little, less than 1% to 0%. It just take some RAM depend on loaded scene. Are you sure Blender load your CPU/GPU? Consider upload screen of running processes. Because this can be everything, most likely some mining visus.

Comment: @Shubol3D: I checked to be sure: I don't see any significant activity on the CPU using Resource Monitor or Process Explorer, and the latter tells me there is no significant GPU use either. [Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBEUq.png). Still air is a bit hot, and Windows doesn't go on sleep state. Closing Blender, air seems colder and the computer sleeps and then hibernates normally.

Comment: hmm, I don't thing this have something to do with Blender. Based on your screenshot looks like it's more about your hardware condition. Hot air in almost zero CPU load  = something wrong with cooling system. I don't know your situation and it's out of topic here. This was discussed millions times all over the internet.  :)

Comment: @Shubol3D: For temperature, I'm not talking about very hight one, and I don't exclude [the fan need some cleaning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0Rrq.jpg). However I this has likely no impact in the sleep issue.

Comment: powercfg -requests shows an audio stream being active any time blender is open