# Rendering animation frames with GPU and CPU

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Assuming I am not using any shaders which are CPU only, would you recommend against mixing GPU and CPU Cycles network rendering of an animation?

Comment: Which rendering engine?

Comment: BI doesn't support GPU for final rendering, so I assume Cycles?

Comment: Yes, Cycles, I'll edit the question

Comment: I don't have a GPU myself, but I don't see any reason why you wouldn't want to. Do you have any specific concerns?

Comment: Related: [Cycles hybrid rendering](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3232/599)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I open two blenders to render with my GPU/CPU?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6862/should-i-open-two-blenders-to-render-with-my-gpu-cpu)

Answer (score 1):

No, I would not recommend against it, mainly because even if there are problems with hybrid rendering with the native network renderer, it's REALLY easy to get around it. By rendering to a network location and turning ON "Placeholders" and turning OFF "Overwrite," any computers rendering to that location will sort it all out themselves, very nicely. This doesn't automate nearly as well as the Network Renderer (i.e. not at all), so if that's important to you, that would take some scripting.

But in short, there is a way to cooperatively render with multiple computers using a mix of GPU & CPU.