# Should I open two blenders to render with my GPU/CPU?

Tags: rendering

I have a i7-2600 which is currently rendering a scene to .avi and is about 8 hours in and half way.  The CPU is at near 90% usage.

I also have a GTX 460 GPU (which I believe supports CUDA)

Is it a good idea to launch another instance of Blender and configure to render another scene with the GPU instead?  Will this have a negative impact on the other instance of Blender rendering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This should work](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3232/599), but I don't know if you want to risk it because you are rendering directly to a video file.

If the animation render stops the avi file could be corrupted. Not to mention if your computer crashes it will be lost entirely.

This is [why it is considered bad practice to render directly to a video file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/4881/599).

If you were rendering to an image sequence, then it wouldn't be a big deal even if your computer crashed completely because everything up to the previous frame would be on the hard drive.

**To answer your question:**
Performance wise, I tested this with a GTX 460 and a quad core intel xeon rendering two separate scenes in separate instances of blender.

There was a slight slowdown on the CPU scene when I started the GPU render, but it was barely noticeable. What made me certain that there was indeed a slowdown is that the time estimation for the CPU render jumped backwards about a second or two when the GPU render was started.