# is there any cpu gpu hybrid render addon for blender

Tags: rendering, add-on, gpu

is there any cpu gpu hybrid render addon for blender similar to luxrender hybrid path but more gpu optimized? If there is I would like to know

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cycles hybrid rendering](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3232/cycles-hybrid-rendering)

Comment: No I want to find a add-on that's not cycles

Comment: I don't know of any besides Cycles and Luxrender. There is Octane, a commercial renderer with a blender addon, but it doesn't support CPU rendering AFAIK.

Comment: AFALK, commercial render engines that have addon for Blender include: Octane render and Thearender (Vray for Blender might support GPU rendering feature but I'm not sure yet).