# Can I use both GPU and CPU together when I render with Cycles to decrease render time?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Is it possible to use both GPU and CPU on a single render? I guess that the GPU and CPU should render the whole frame so it doesn't have different pieces rendered by CPU and a few other by GPU so the image looks weird because of the differences in the two render methods.
I don't want to run two independent instances of blender that might crash the other with 100%lode problems, or just end a half hour before the other.
The other is how do I make the GPU and CPU render the same style, I know i have seen very different result between CPU and CUDA render.

if you are working on a animation you shulde reed this also, the method disused ther is runing two independent rendering on the same time. 
[Cycles hybrid rendering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3232/cycles-hybrid-rendering)

Comment: No, that thred did disus runing two difrent rendering on the same time, this is for runing one.

Comment: "Is it possible to render with Cycles using both the CPU, and GPU? If not are there any other workarounds that maximize the hardware's potential?"  - It's from question.

Comment: Reed the answers, they are talking abute runing two instance of blender working on different frames

Comment: ... From first answer: "If you want to render a single image, you can set a different seed in the Sampling panel and render for example 2000 samples with the CPU and 4000 with the GPU and overlay both images in the compositor"

Comment: That will make things hard to balens the sampels, the second problem is that the cpu is building the BVH. The last problem is, how the hell do I synk the difrent rendring methods so the materials work the same, I have seen way to difrent variation on the rendering result to think I just can merge two difrent result.