# How to make a renderfarm

Tags: rendering, linux

I want to know how I can make a simple renderfarm. I won't use the network render plugin because it is boring and doesn't support single image rendering (it does so only rendering it on one node).
So is there any scalable solution for building a big rendering cluster like ILM (Industrial Light and Magic) is using with loads of cores and ram.
As operating system, ubuntu or some other linux distributions should be used.

It should be a free and easy solution.

Comment: Also related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15844/599

Comment: Thanks! But is there a way of an automation system? Because when you have for example 1000 single servers it is a pain in the ass to set up the whole farm..

Comment: An automation for the second technique or the first one? BTW, this question has a way to get netrender to render a single frame: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2002/599

Comment: I will have to read me into BURP tomorrow.. an automation for this... I don't exactly know how the renderfarm at ILM works, but something like that would be really cool...