# Is there a way to stop Blender from performing an action once started?

Tags: workflow

For example, sometimes I accidentally switch to Material view for objects instead of Textured and since my computer is very slow, it takes WAY too long until I can do anything again. So, I'd like to be able to hit a key and have Blender stop trying to display Material view.

Comment: Nope.. I don't think this is possible.

Comment: I didn't think so but it'd be SO useful!

Comment: Alt + 4 will stop the action by stopping blender full stop. Other than you hit esc during certain times only.

Comment: @Vader Alt+4 switches to layer 14..

Comment: Will that mess up anything, like leave it in an unstable state?

Comment: @ThomBlairIII I think Vader means Alt+f4, which will kill blender.

Comment: By "kill" do you mean quit?

Comment: Yes. http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/582/599

Comment: Oh, I just want to hit esc or break. Thanks though!

Comment: @ThomBlairIII I meant Alt + F4 not Alt + 4

Comment: This would be a really valuable feature.  It is very easy to click the wrong button (e.g. Bevel rather than Boolean) which will crash the program on a complicated model.  Other programs (e.g. PTC Creo) have the ability to cancel any operation by pressing the Pause/Break button which can avoid hangups or forced process kills.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends, some actions you can stop, others you cannot. However you can always stop blender by closing it <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> or killing the process. Some things can be stopped in blender. If it is possible to stop an action you can do it with the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key.

**Actions that cannot be stopped:**

- Changing shading style in the viewport, e.g changing to textured or materials can take some time if you have a lot of textures, there is no way to stop this
- Applying/Modifying modifiers, e.g when you accidently increase the numbers of arrays to 400 blender will take a long time to compute this depending on the complexity of the object. Same goes for other modifiers.

**Actions you can stop mid process:**

- Rendering, you can always abort a render at render time
- Baking textures, similar to render: e.g baking a normal map.
- Baking fluids: Smoke and Liquid simulations can be canceled just like renders.

You can also cancel these actions with the GUI by clicking on the X:

[image: enter code here]

Comment: If you are using Linux, you can instantly kill a process by typing the command xkill into the terminal.  After hitting enter, you can click on whatever window you want to kill, and it will end it with speed that is unmatched by any other killing process.  (Pretty much as soon as you click it.)

Comment: I personally think that with modifiers it should be considered a bug. It's way too easy to accidentally tell Blender to perform an operation that it won't finish in a reasonable amount of time, possibly also crashing. It should give some kind of confirmation before starting an action that'll take a long time to complete.