# How to pause Blender or reduce its priority on Mac OS X

Tags: rendering, osx

I am rendering an animation in Blender that should take about two days.
I am using the CPU to render it because Blender does not support my GPU.
After one day non-stop of rendering I have noticed that my iMac (2013 edition, intel core i5 CPU) was getting hot (about 85 degrees) and I do not want it to get harmed.
Unfortunately I have chosen to render the whole animation to a video sequence directly and not to a set of images, so I cannot allow myself to stop the whole process.
So is there any way to pause or reduce Blender's activity so that my computer can cool itself before restarting?

I have already tried the commands renice and killall -s STOP but with no result.

Comment: Nevermind, I found out a pretty efficient way. kill -s STOP BLENDER_PID did the job greatly !

Comment: related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/582/how-can-i-pause-a-render-in-progress-and-then-resume-it-at-a-later-time

Comment: You really should have sufficient cooling in your system, if its only a year old take it back to where you got it from. A system should be able to use all resources without getting damaged.