# Is it possible to pause and later resume a fluid sim bake?

Tags: fluid-simulation, baking

I have a pretty heavy fluid sim bake going on... by pretty heavy I mean I estimate it will take two weeks to complete! It is likely that during that time I will sometimes want to use Blender for something else, then resume the fluid bake. I understand mesh data for each frame is stored in bobj.gz files, but can Blender use the file from the last frame to pick up where it left off baking?

Thanks

Comment: In the  current version of blender it is not possible to resume a fluid bake.

Comment: I think you still can try to [pause and resume later Blender work](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/929/1245) by OS utilites. You won't be able to use exactly *that* Blender window, of course, rather than open another one

Answer (score 0):

Two weeks for Fluid bake seems a bit extreme. While there is no way to pause and resume in Blender, have you considered renting a render farm to do it? Render.st now supports baking on their servers.

Comment: Yeah, I normally wouldn't go so high-res, but for this project I cranked up the quality to 1024 (max) hoping the result will be worth it. I'm still considering cancelling it and re-rendering at 512, but even the process of finding the best balance between cost and performance requires time through trial and error, so for now I've decided to wait it out. That's good to know that Render.st supports baking though - I'll look into it.

Comment: They don't support baking

Answer (score 0):

You can use the addon flip fluids which you can pause a bake with extra features like seafoam, only thing is that it has a watermark on the demo addon.