# Stop animation render after current frame

Tags: rendering, interface

For long running animation renders, is there a way to stop the render once the current frame is finished? I leave my machine rendering over night, and when I return the next day, I want to stop the render to free up resources. However, I don't want to stop the render immediately and lose any progress on the current frame, and I also don't want to monitor the render and cancel it manually once the current frame finishes.

Is there a way to do this automatically, be it via the main interface, an addon, or another method?

Comment: No, there is no such functionality. Use a directory watcher like DirWatcher or similar to get a notification when a file is written into directory.

Comment: see if this helps http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/595/5113

Comment: @Chebhou, that method is similar in what it achieves, and will probably be helpful for some people finding this question, but it has a few rough edges. Manually suspending processes is not very user friendly, and the system will still be sluggish under memory pressure until the OS swaps Blender out.

Comment: Always bizarre to Google a question and click through to a relevant-looking SE post, find it's exactly the situation you're dealing with, then realize you're the one that wrote it. Two years later and still running into this.