# Render checkpoints during long renders

Tags: rendering

I've tried to render a complex scen for my first time. The reported time was 23 hours but after some 14+ hours the computer restarted for unknown reason. In case I'll face a similar situation in the future, is there any way to save a checkpoint image of an ongoing render? Or even better, is it possible to create checkpoints of the entire rendering for crash recovery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pause a render in progress and then resume it at a later time?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/582/how-can-i-pause-a-render-in-progress-and-then-resume-it-at-a-later-time) Basically the same, as there is no way to resume a single frame render at this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's standard practice to do this with animations, as described [in this video](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/rendering-animations/).  If your scene has no animation, you can use the same technique for still images by rendering one vertical strip at a time, by animating the camera settings.

For example, to render the image in 20 vertical strips, set the horizontal resolution of your image to 1/20 of the desired image width, and set the Frame Range to 1...20.  Then with the camera selected, [add keyframes](https://www.blender.org/manual/en/animation/key_frames.html) to the X Shift property:

[image]
[image]

Set X Shift to -0.95 in frame 1 and 0.95 in frame 20.  Go to the graph editor and make sure the property is using linear interpolation.  The curve should be a straight line like this:

[image]

After rendering your scene as an animation (using the method described in the video), you will have twenty images that you can stitch together using Photoshop or Gimp.

Comment: This looks like a complete hack, but at the same time it has some beauty to it. Thanks!

Comment: @Hyperdrive I guess I can't argue about it being a hack.  :-) I hope you find it useful anyway.