# pause blender project and restart and continue after a day.

Tags: animation

I am doing a project by placing new text  in 20th century fox logo .I want to pause my on going blender project and then restart the same project. how do I do it?. the project is half done. now i want to pause it and restart it again later.

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! With "project" do you mean the "rendering of the animation"? Give a look at this similar question: [How can I pause a render in progress and then resume it at a later time?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/582/how-can-i-pause-a-render-in-progress-and-then-resume-it-at-a-later-time)

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, you can't pause an ongoing render, but for future reference there is a way to get similar functionality. You can render your video as a series of PNG images and then put them all together at the end.

First, in the render tab, go to output and make sure PNG is selected. Point it to an empty folder on a disk with plenty of space because it is going to spit out a lot of images.

Then when you click render animation it will make a PNG for each frame. When you stop the render, you can just set the start frame to the last frame it rendered and then continue.

Once you've rendered the whole thing, take all the images and put them together into your video. This guy does a pretty good job of explaining how:
https://youtu.be/OGapXgrLOnI

Comment: There is no need to modify the start and end frame to be rendered. Just disable  the **Overwrite** option in the output settings. Blender will only  render the missing frames leaving the rendered ones untouched.