# Trying to finish a blend-file before the 20th for my daughter

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, performance

So, I've followed all the tutorials that I can find, and as straight forward as it seems, it just ain't. I load the template, I change the text, I set the output file, go to render and it starts, everything looks great and it renders up to 99% in about 3 mins then just closes itself and doesn't leave a file. I'm dying to get this done before the 30th as it's for her birthday and she's obsessed with 20th c-fox.

I'm running a 78702gb with an a10 7850k & 12gb 1600mhz ram, **Blender 2.79a** win32. I downloaded the template from [this youtube tutorial](https://youtube.com/watch?v=NbixwwuSY-U) and have tried several others, I've tried image formats as well as different video formats to render to, it just keeps closing and creating a blank file (0bytes) - here's the temp I changed

Blend file: https://filebin.net/kd29v2vc5k5hol2f

**Test with Blender 2.92**

Render works without compositing in Eevee and Cycles:
[image: render without compositing]

Blender always crashes in Eevee and Cycles when these nodes are used for compositing. After deletion and recreation of the node setup Blender works fine. The recreated *Composite* node looks different.
[image: compositing nodes]

Comment: Provide your blend file. Looks like you are a beginner and until you have shown us all settings and screenshots we need to tell you what‘s wrong - you are much faster with providing your blend file

Comment: Is this an animation or image to render? (For an animation it is better to render all images as png files and create the video file from the single images.) Which render engine is used?

Comment: blender 2.79a win32, i downloaded the template from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NbixwwuSY-U this tutorial and have tried several others, i've tried image formats as well as different video formats to render to, it just keeps closing and creating a blank file (0bytes) - here's the temp i changed https://filebin.net/kd29v2vc5k5hol2f

Comment: ok, your question is now closed - maybe open another one -> you can open as many as you want, but next time with more info ;) i recommend to change the output  -> file format to png under render properties, so whenever your computer crashes, you still have all images so far. Then you just need to render the rest. When your computer is ready with rendering all images you can easily open blender again with file -> new -> video editing, put in all your images there and make a video out of it.

Comment: Instead of adding comments, please use the [edit] link at the bottom 
of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more 
information on how you set up your project.
[Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that 
might help us understand your scene and settings.
See [How to add an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102265/pause-blender-project-and-restart-and-continue-after-a-day

Comment: You can edit your question and after review, it can be opened again. -- About the problem: I've tested your provided file in Blender 2.92. It crashes Blender every time if I just render the image. It's the composite node setup for some reason. If I disabled/delete/recreate it then it works fine. The file is a 2.79 file. The Blender 2.8 is a major update despite the small increase in version number. Update your Blender if you can and use at least the 2.83 version. Then fix the nodes in the compositing tab and use PNGs to render the animation. Have a look here: https://youtu.be/zTWWlyOf8n8